# Change CSS properties on display with css transitions?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

It's easy enough to change css properties on hover/focus with css transitions but is it possible to do so on the appearance of an element?

One possibe way is to do it with animation. If I want to create an increasing opacity effect when the element appears I can do the following:

```
.element {
  color: #1dd1a1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  opacity:0;
  animation: animOpacity 2s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animOpacity {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

That way, the element will appear with increasing opacity. Is there a more elegant way to do so without the use of animation? I've heard that css animations exploit more memory than css transitions

Thanks in advance

Comment: *more memory* --> I don't think I will be something really significant

Comment: there is no `transition` between css properties  when adding a new element to the dom... so easy

Comment: So guys, the method that I show in my question is considered best practice? Thanks

Comment: there isn't a *best practice*. You have a found a way to make it working with logical properties, this is the purpose. Someone may find something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no CSS `transition` for when an element "appears". Using CSS Animations is the most elegant way to do what you are describing. The memory difference between transitions and animations shouldn't be an issue.